# Django postgresql drop all tables and syncdb

Tags: django, postgresql, sh, postgresql-9.1

I have database in PostgreSql named "tests".
And i want to write sh script to syncdb it with django, run tests and then drop all tables.
Can anyone suggest a proper solution?
A bit of script:

```
DJANGO_DATABASE='tests' bin/django-admin.py syncdb  
bin/django-admin.py test MyApplication #tests will use "tests" db
sudo su postgres
psql tests
drop schema public; #i think i can drop schema and then syncdb.. or i'm wrong.
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, [django can do this for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#the-test-database). <-- **outdated**

Actually, it changed a bit :).
But it's still possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
./manage.py sqlclear | ./manage.py dbshell
./manage.py syncdb
```

this will pipe, the output of `sqlclear` management-command into the `dbshell`.
which will in turn execute it.

`sqlclear` will output `DROP TABLE ...` sql-statements.

Comment: Great!  Can you explain how?